# Merge multiple 3D arrays matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, merge

I have a 3 sets of CT data each in it's own 700x700x512 array and I want to merge them into just one single array.

I had a look at the `cat()` function but didn't really understand how you set the `dim` variable- i.e. say for two simple 3x3x3 arrays, A & B, can I use `AB_merge = cat(dim, A, B);`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why not try it and find out? Type `size(AB_merge)` to see the size of the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dim` variable sets along which dimension you want to concatenate the images.

So if you want them 'on top of each other' that is along the 3rd dimensions:

```
AB_merge=cat(3, A, B);
```

If it is side by side along the x-axis:

```
AB_merge=cat(1, A, B);
```

etc.